# Looking for sans serif typeface with interesting Q and &. Ideas?

Tags: typefaces

I am looking for a sans serif typeface with interesting Q and &.

Comment: Something free and on CTAN, or a commercial typeface?

Comment: What is an interesting `Q`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Interesting depends mainly on personal taste, and questions that are opinion-based are usually closed. It would better if you posted a picture of the characters you wish (or similar). Anyway, take a look at the `garamondx` package. It has an "interesting Q"...

Comment: You may have better luck asking this on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/. It will still be opinion-based (not sure how strict they are and how they handle this), but it will be more on topic there than here.

Comment: Have a look at the package libertine-legacy. Install it, `texdoc -s libertine`and choose »libertineglyph«. Biolinum is the sans serif fonts and on p. 122 you'll find ampersands and interesting Q_u ligatures and much more.